# ng-change not working in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two textarea, I want to use the content on the first to update the second immediately the user clicks the textarea using ng-change. Bt when I click on the textarea, no update is made. Below is the two textarea

```
<textarea ng-change="content=emojiMessage.messagetext | colonToCode" placeholder="emoji..." ng-bind="emojiMessage.messagetext | colonToCode" id="messageInput"></textarea>


    <input ng-hide="false" type="text" id="message" name="message" ng-model="content" value="{{content}}" />
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: did you try `ng-focus`?

Comment: In place of where I used ng-change?

Comment: Explain behavior in more detail. `ng-change` won't do anything until there is an actual change. Also no point in setting `value` when using `ng-model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the snippet is using ng-focus instead, but with the same function.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('colonToCode', function(){
  return function (data) {
            return data + ' Something added by the filter';
        };
  });

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.content = 'Something';
  $scope.emojiMessage = {
    messagetext: 'smilie face'
  };
  
  $scope.setContent = function(text){
    $scope.content = $filter('colonToCode')(text);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <textarea ng-focus="setContent(emojiMessage.messagetext)" placeholder="emoji..." ng-model="emojiMessage.messagetext" id="messageInput"></textarea>


    <input ng-hide="false" type="text" id="message" name="message" ng-model="content" value="{{content}}" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, your second textarea has ng-model="content", so if you change $scope.content in your controller, it should update in the second textarea.

Comment: Is missing filter used by OP

Comment: You can actually update scope objects directly in the markup using `ng-change` as the OP is doing and it will work. It's probably not the best practice, though.

Comment: @aup if I change the first textarea to a div will it work?

Comment: Try the snippet with an example

Comment: How do I add the filter?

Comment: I added a filter in the setContent-function now as well.